3d object should always "fit" inside the window with Orthographic Camera
I want my 3d objects to always "fit" inside the window
This is how my code currently looks like
export function onWindowResize(camera, renderer) {
  const canvas = renderer.domElement;
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;
  const connection = getBoundingBox(connectionGroup);
  const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
  const isPortrait = connection.width < connection.height;

  if (needResize) renderer.setSize(width, height);

  const aspect = isPortrait ? width / height : height / width;
  const frustumSize = Math.max(connection.width, connection.height);

  //Front View
  if (isPortrait) {
    camera.left = (-frustumSize * aspect) / 2;
    camera.right = (frustumSize * aspect) / 2;
    camera.top = frustumSize / 2;
    camera.bottom = -frustumSize / 2;
  } else {
    camera.left = -frustumSize / 2;
    camera.right = frustumSize / 2;
    camera.top = (frustumSize * aspect) / 2;
    camera.bottom = (-frustumSize * aspect) / 2;
  }

  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

Currently, everything works as expected: the object fits in the window based on its height or width. A problem occurs if the object's height exceeds the window height but still fits within the maximum width (vice-versa), causing the model to be cropped.
I only need to fit the object on the initial display, user can perform orbit controls freely after that
MAX WIDTH
MAX HEIGHT
MAX WIDTH but models height exceed window/camera height
I tried manually setting camera.zoom, but even then, I couldn't figure out the right value for it. After that, my orbit controls stopped functioning.

Could you describe more precisely what your expectations are? ...Currently, everything works as expected: the object fits in the window... - what do you mean by this? Model should be stretched in width and height, and these values should be depend on window? Or should remain scale, regardless on window?

The code I'm currently using works as expected. It behaves similarly to the CSS object-fit: contain property. The model always fits within the window, even when the window is resized. It adjusts to fit based on either the width or height, depending on whether the model's width or height is greater.
However, the problem I encounter is when the model fits to the window's width, but the model's height exceeds the window's height, resulting in a cropped projection (see third image).

Calculations should account for a special case when the ratio of window dimensions (aspect) is less than the ratio of connection dimensions (frustumAspect). The frustumSize should be scaled to reflect that difference (frustumScaled).
Optionally, camera.left and camera.bottom can be simplified by negating the opposite properties.
const frustumAspect = isPortrait ? (connection.width / connection.height) :
  (connection.height / connection.width);

const aspectScale = Math.max(frustumAspect / aspect, 1);
const frustumScaled = frustumSize * aspectScale;

//Front View
if (isPortrait) {
  camera.right = (frustumScaled * aspect) / 2;
  camera.top = frustumScaled / 2;
} else {
  camera.right = frustumScaled / 2;
  camera.top = (frustumScaled * aspect) / 2;
}
camera.left = -camera.right;
camera.bottom = -camera.top;

